# Should I add a slash to self-closing HTML tags like `img` and `br`?

Tags: html, tags, w3c, slash

What is the main difference between:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

and

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

I understand that this is related to the fact that the tags that are getting `/>` instead of `>` don't have closing tags, but what is the benefit of using `/>` on HTML, PHP and ASP documents?

Comment: @AshReva, this question is about tag syntax, not about closing tags.

Answer (score 3):

Not closing tags is now HTML5 valid for void elements (such like `img`, `br`...)

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Adding the closing `/>` is still valid, and in my personal opinion (only personal), it may get deprecated in a near future.

> Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements.

Reference: [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html)

EDIT: Of course, not closing tags is invalid for `XHTML`

Comment: not in html5, this code valid in xhtml format.

Comment: That is what I'm saying. I edited the answer for more clarity